# List of groups with specific divisors

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I want to find list of finite simple nonabelian groups which their orders divisor lies in specific set of primes for example the set $\{2,3,5,7,11\}$.

Is there a method to do this? Would Zsigmondy's theorem help?

Comment: I think the way to do it is to start by finding a list of the orders of finite simple nonabelian groups. Probably not too hard to chase up such a thing by a little websearching.

Comment: None have even order, as such a group is soluble (aka solvable). You should look up the ATLAS of finite simple groups. It gives a description of all finite simple groups (for some values of "description" and "all").

Comment: @Jyrki Gah! Sorry, the first sentence should have been "*All* have even order, as odd-order groups are soluble". Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

The *ATLAS of finite groups* is a large, red book, and was written by John Conway, Robert Curtis, Simon Norton, Richard Parker, and Robert Wilson. It lists information about $93$ finite simple groups, including their orders.

All the sporadic simple groups are covered in the ATLAS. Simple groups which are not covered are the large ones which are part of a family, so the familial (that's a nice word!) information can be used to find the order of such groups (for example, $A_{n}$ for $n\geq 11$ contains all your listed prime divisors).

There is an online continuation of the ATLAS, which can be found [here](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/atlas/v2.0/).